# I am trying to get contact form 7 data to zoho crm ,it is working fine on local host but on live it is giving following error

Tags: wordpress, api, contact-form-7, zoho

It is working fine in localhost but when i updating it on live site it giving following error-

{"data":[{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"maximum_length":20,"api_name":"Subscribed_Newsletter"},"message":"invalid data","status":"error"}]}

You can find the reference code below-

add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','brainium_cf7_api_sender');

function brainium_cf7_api_sender($contact_form){

```
$title = $contact_form->title;

if( $title === 'Test') {

   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if( $submission ){
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $first_name = $posted_data['first-name'];
        $last_name = $posted_data['last-name'];
        $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
        $phone = $posted_data['Phone-no'];
        $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
        $budget = $posted_data['budget'];
        $checkbox = $posted_data['checkbox-37'][0];
                          

        $auth = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        //get the last date and time of refresh token generation
        
        //get the access token
        $url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token";
        $query = "refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token";
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //get the token from the JSON in result
        $accessToken =  json_decode($result, true);
        //echo ($accessToken['access_token']); 
        //die();        
        
        $data = array("First_Name"=>$first_name, "Last_Name"=>$last_name, "Email"=>$email, "Phone"=>$phone, "Description"=>($message), "Budget"  => $budget, 'Subscribed_Newsletter' => $checkbox, "Lead_Date"=>$zoho_date, '$gclid'=>$zc_gad);
        //$data = json_encode($data);
        
        $encodedData = array();
        $encodedData['data'][0] = $data;
        
        //var_dump($data);
        //echo(json_encode($encodedData));
        //die();
        //che


        $url ="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";
        $headers = array(
                            'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken '.$accessToken['access_token'],
                            'Content-Type:application/json'
                        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //echo $result;
        // End zoho CRM
        $success = true;
        $msg = 'Done';
        
        $leadSaving = print_r($result, true);
        $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . $email;
        $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . "request quote";
        file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", $leadSaving, FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", "\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this different than the question you posted the other day?

Comment: hi...yes i am working on localhost before and it is working fine but as i move to live server it showing the error as i mention above